# What do the commands with dashes/hyphens ("-l", "-o") mean in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have no idea what commands like "-l" or "-i" or "-o" do in PowerShell. I suspect it is probably one of the most basic things in scripting in PowerShell but I couldn't find any explanation online.

Could somebody provide any explanation of what those shortcuts do?

Comment: Those aren't commands in PowerShell but they could be options to commands.

Comment: script i am working with basically runs one .exe program and then calls additional files the .exe program generates. I don't see any commands in this script, there are only calls to files and -l -o -r -r2 "options"

Comment: What are the file extensions?

Comment: What does "calls to files" mean. Please copy and paste in text mode some of the code into the question.

Answer (score 2):

- In PowerShell each cmdlet has it's own set of [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-6) (aside from [Common Paramters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6))
- parameter names can be abbreviated as long they are uniquely identifiable.
- to know what `-l`, `-i` or `-o` means you have to name the individual cmdlet
- a cmdlet can have different sets of parameters you can enumerate with:
  `(Get-Command Get-Help).ParameterSets`

---

Answer (score 0):

The options for each command are different; you would need to look at the command definition to determine the meaning of the option. For PowerShell cmdlets, you can often get this information from the `Get-Help` cmdlet (e.g., `Get-Help Get-ChildItem`); for external programs (`.EXE` files), you would need to consult the documentation for the program.